# how to use cordova api in external webpage

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I created a mobile application based on iOS platform and Android platform using cordova.I want to set it`s content to an external web site page, so I don't need to update every mobile device, just to update the page on the server。

At first I set external page as cordova starting page: `loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html")`. The app could run but use cordova API failed.

Then I use local web page as starting page, add the external web link to navigate to the external page. The app still can`t use cordova API.

I try to use cordova inappbrowser plugin, but I noticed that it has a comment : `The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content, instead of loading that into the main Cordova webview. The InAppBrowser is not subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links in the system browser.`

I found some app has the function which external web page use device camera or record sound just like cordova, but I`m not sure it uses cordova or its own framework.

Is there any way to use the Cordova API in an external web page?

Comment: I figured out how to use the Cordova API in an external web page on android platform. Just need change some source code of cordova lib.In `CordovaBridge.java` file.

Comment: you need comment these code:`if (pluginManager.shouldAllowBridgeAccess(origin)) {
                // Enable the bridge
                int bridgeMode = Integer.parseInt(defaultValue.substring(9));
                jsMessageQueue.setBridgeMode(bridgeMode);
                // Tell JS the bridge secret.
                int secret = generateBridgeSecret();
                return ""+secret;
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "gap_init called from restricted origin: " + origin);
            }`

Comment: simply add these code: `int bridgeMode = Integer.parseInt(defaultValue.substring(9));
            jsMessageQueue.setBridgeMode(bridgeMode);
            // Tell JS the bridge secret.
            int secret = generateBridgeSecret();
            return ""+secret;`

Comment: Then you could use cordova API on external web page on Android platform.I just tested it by using camera plugin. I'm still analyzing the Cordova source code for the iOS platform.

Comment: Any luck with the iOS source code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have following lines into your config xml?

```
<content src="[YOUR URL]"/>
   <access origin="*" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: Very useful. The important line is eventually "<allow-navigation href="*" />", because when creating a new project (through Cordova), this line is not listed in the config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your Cordova application for browser

```
cordova platforms add browser
cordova build browser
```

This is standard way of building Corodova application for browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think through the inApp Browser provided by Cordova you may not be able to use the Cordova API's, what other apps may be doing is by creating interface between JavaScript and the Native Side. It is a little less restricted in case of android as it is in case of IOS(for example To access the FileSystem). Anyways I think what might help you is to look at this Project [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)

With Cordova 4.0 you can plug the Crosswalk Webview as it says in its description and you should be able to use native API's with or without Cordova.

Hope this Helps.